# TabLayout performance issue

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a ViewPager linked to a tablayout. I use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter to populate my adapter and i link it with the SetupWithViewPager to the tabLayout.

If i add 500 fragment to my viewpager, it take something like 2 second before to be displayed.

If i remove the link to the TabLayout and delete it, there is no Lag, everything is displayed directly.

Is there something to cache the items tabLayout that are not displayed ???

Does someone has an idea ?

EDIT:

```
[MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame, true)]
[Register("mvvmcrosslearning.droid.fragments.DateFragment")]
public class DateFragment : BaseFragment<DateViewModel>
{
    protected override int FragmentId => Resource.Layout.fragment_date;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var viewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
        var tabLayout = view.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            if (viewPager == null) return;

            var fragments = new List<MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
                fragments.Add(new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo(
                    $"Ceci est du text : {i}",
                    typeof(RecyclerViewFragment),
                    typeof(RecyclerViewModel),
                    new Device() { Date = $"index from frag: {i}" }
                ));

            Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => viewPager.Adapter =
                new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter(Activity, ChildFragmentManager, fragments));

            viewPager.OffscreenPageLimit = 1;

            tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }).Start();

        return view;
    }
}
```

and the view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 android:id="@+id/main_content"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

There is juste a simple button in the fragment.

Comment: attach you code

Comment: When you delete the `tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager)`,  the lag disappeared?

Comment: Yes it disappear

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo to reproduce this problem?

Comment: were you able to fix this? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known bug and is being tracked here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37053935